# Do radioactive materials have a property for their natural heat output?

Tags: temperature, radioactivity, popular-science

Consider room temperature, would a fissile/fissionable element be naturally warmer to the touch (or a sensitive thermometer) compared to say a glass of water (because the atoms have more ongoing activity)?

I found [this graph](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Emissive_Power.svg) that shows the radiative power of a human, and *of course* it stays warmer than a room due to the internal energy release (and regulation).

Since fissioning releases energy, I expected to find such a parameter/property, even in table format for all the elements – perhaps a $\Delta K$ or a $K$ figure in vacuum. As far as I can tell, no such parameter is in the Wikipedia articles for [U-238](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-238) and [U-235](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-235), likewise for [periodictable.com](https://periodictable.com/Isotopes/092.235/index.html). Even though the U-238 article says:

> Due to its natural abundance and half-life relative to other radioactive elements, 238U produces ~40% of the radioactive heat produced within the Earth.

So I'm guessing such a parameter/property exists, and such a material would be warmer to the touch. (And thinking out loud, does such a property limit how cold an element can get?) If not, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: For U-238 it's about 8.5E-09 W/g

Comment: @Loong: Thank you. That's tiny! Does it have a name, and if possible where can I find it? (I'd also accept that as an answer.)

Comment: You might want to look for "isotopic power", e.g. https://www.nucleonica.com/wiki/index.php?title=Isotopic_power or simply "decay heat", e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decay_heat

Comment: In material about the Manhattan Project and the Trinity test, they talk about how the core was warm to the touch.

Comment: A strong radioactive source is said to be "hot" for a reason.